# multipeerConnectivity unable to find invitees, between device and simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, multipeer-connectivity

I try to use the connectivity peer demo project (multipeerChat), between my device and the simulator. But they cannot find one another, although they are on the same wifi network. I created a room, I tried to remove the app and relaunch it, just in case, but it does not solve the issue.

Is there something I could do to debug this? The browsePeers method is called, and the loading animation never stops.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: @ChrisH I just used the sample code from Apple (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MultipeerGroupChat/Introduction/Intro.html), then I launch the simulator, I run the app, I stop it. The app is in the simulator now, so I can launch the app in the device, create a room, open the app from the simulator, and look for invitees, but it is searching with the loading animation forever.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in the iOS Simulator at this time.

Comment: What isn't supported? MPC between the simulator and devices works just fine for me.

Comment: MultiPeerConnectivity.framework isn't supported in the iOS Simulator.  It may work in some situations, but the core functionality is not available because the simulated device is tied too closely to the host OS.  I would expect that you would not be able to discover the sim from real devices or other sims, but you might be able to discover devices from the sim.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia Have you tried? I cannot try it (problem with the wifi), but if it is sure, I will continue my work on the current project, and test with the wifi later on.